# GDB Server - How do you attach multiple processes from multiple machines?

Tags: process, gdb

So I'm intending to use a framework called ROS to write software for a new robot. Under the ROS framework, each software component it run as a separate process. Additionally, since ROS is designed to work on multiple machines at once through TCP message sharing, my setup will involve multiple processes on multiple machines.

Now I want to be able to run a gdb server and attach all the processes from each machine so that when I hit a break point, I can suspend all processes.

Looking at the documention for gdb:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html

It details that you can attach multiple processes to the gdb server through the command:

gdbserver --attach comm pid

However, on the machine running the gdb server, you won't have the pid of processes running on other machines. How would you go about attaching multiple processes from different machines to the same gdb server? And if it's not possible, how would you go about setting up multiple gdb servers and have them talk to each other such that one suspending suspends others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't currently be done -- gdb can only connect to one remote target at a time.  Work in this area is ongoing; it is called the "[multi target](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/MultiTarget)" project.  That wiki page is a bit out of date; someone else has picked up the work but not updated the page.

Comment: BTW there was a talk on this at the latest GNU Cauldron.  Slides: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cauldron2017?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=GDB+%26+Multi-target.pdf ; video: https://slideslive.com/38902683/the-gdb-bof-gdb-multitarget

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to be able to run a gdb server and attach all the processes from each machine so that when I hit a break point, I can suspend all processes.

In addition to the impossibility of this (as Tom Tromey answered), it's also *infeasible* -- it is not humanly possible to debug more than 2-3 processes at once (you are talking 10s or processes here), and even if it were possible, your processes (running on separate hosts) will not all stop "at once" -- there will be some delays. And as soon as there are 100ms or more delays, you could just as well let these processes run without stopping, and only stop and attach them manually when necessary.

Finally, a lot of ROS processes will likely have timers and assertions that "not too much time has passed since last timer", etc. Debugging such processes with GDB becomes infeasible: you stop them once, look around, continue and they immediately assert that system is not executing as designed (and crash).